# Solution to a timed out/End Date event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, vb.net

Hopefully someone can help me to look in the right direction for a solution to this issue I've come across during the design of a system.

I am creating an auction site in which the auction has a particular end date/time.

I have a .NET Timer displaying the remaining time to the user and when this countsdown it fires and event to update the back end SQL database to say the auction has completed and it informs the winning user and fires a CLOSE function.

How would you recommend doing this for auctions that aren't physically open in a browser at the time so the Timer event never creates this CLOSE event.

Ideally I need to run something at the point in time when an auction closing time has passed?

Thanks

Comment: What did you end up going with here?  Did the answers help?

Comment: I've had to go for a slightly different approach because the site is on a shared hosting solution for the moment so I cannot have a service running so I'm using this solution...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc

but in the DoWork part I check for the auctionEnddate being < Now and going from there, sending emails to the buyer and seller and closing the auction status down.

Works really well and I have it checking every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to store in the database the date/time that the auction item ends/closes.  Then, don't worry about something reacting to it closing (timer in your case on the client) and updating it closed.  What determines it's closed is simply the fact that now > closed date/time.

EDIT:

In the comment below you stated you also need to send mail when an auction closes.  If that's the case, you need some sort of background processing to select all events that are closed and send mails.  You can still define closed by storing a date time.  That bg processing can select all events where now is greater than closed date and processed bit is false.  Once you select those, put them in a durable queue (table in sql, azure queue etc...).  Then have the background processing drain the queue.  As it processes each item and sends mail, it updates the event as processed.

You have multiple options for background processing:

1. Windows Service
2. In proc timer with a threadpool to process (only do this if you have one AT)
3. Worker role in Azure
4. Sql Agent Job

Comment: +1 Unlike my answer, which requires a service, this solution negates the need to update any flag at all, and instead uses business logic to indicate the auction expired.

Comment: Hi @bryanmac,  I am storing the date/time the auction closes in my DB and the timer on the page currently uses this.  But if a user doesn't have the page open then the close event will never fire so the answer below about a windows service effectively listening to when an auction has ended might be the best answer?

Comment: That adds a bunch of complexity, moving parts, and latency you don't need.  Instead, simply don't update closed.  Store the date an event is closed with that event and the definition of whether it's closed is if it's currently past that date.

Comment: For example, when the browser reads the event from the server, the page would show closed if now > closed data retrieved.  You can also make the server reject bids etc... if now > closed date for event.

Comment: Another variation of the solution (if you need a closed bit) is to create a calculated column based on the date closed.  The uber point is to avoid needing something "watching" each event to update.

Comment: Sorry I did mention it needs to inform the user but didn't put by email.  I'll look into writing a Windows Service for it (I wasn't aware of these beforehand).  I would have normally written a small SQL Job that checks the auction end date < now but I don't have access to SQL Jobs as I'm on a shared SQL.  Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Write a Windows service that polls the database at a set amount of time (I'd say a little less than the minimum length of an auction.  For an example, say a day).  That service would store in memory actions that will end within that amount of time, and check every second whether there are actions that ended.  For auctions that have ended, fire your CLOSE event.

Comment: I think this may be the best way to look at it but I'll need to look into how Windows Services work.  I effectively want to email the winning bidder and close the auction when the auction has "ended" so I can run this when the windows service is checking these times I hope!

Comment: In your question, you didn't say needed to email when it closes.  If you need to do that then you need something background worker (like a windows service or bg thread) to check for closed auctions.  At that point, you can use a combination of the two approaches.

Comment: +1 since a hybrid of the two is likely needed (didn't initially say sending mail needed).

Comment: Actually, instead of firing every second, when the service starts, you can find out when the first auction ends, and they wait until that time.  Unless you will be able to allow users to change when an auction ends (I assume not).